# How to keep a list of 'used' data per user

Tags: sql, mongodb, database, nosql

I'm currently working on a project in MongoDB where I want to get a random sampling of new products from the DB.  But my problem is not MongoDB specific, I think it's a general database question.

The scenario:

Let's say we have a collection (or table) of products.  And we also have a collection (or table) of users.  Every time a user logs in, they are presented with 10 products.  These products are selected randomly from the collection/table.  Easy enough, but the catch is that every time the user logs in, they must be presented with 10 products that they have NEVER SEEN BEFORE.  The two obvious ways that I can think of solving this problem are:

1. Every user begins with their own private list of all products.  Each time they get one of these products, the product is removed from their private list.  The result is that the next time products are chosen from this previously trimmed list, it already contains only new items.
2. Every user has a private list of previously viewed products.  When a user logs in, they select 10 random products from the master list, compare the id of each against their list of previously viewed products, and if the item appears on the previously viewed list, the application throws this one away selects a new one, and iterates until there are 10 new items, which it then adds to the previously viewed list for next time.

The problem with #1 is it seems like a tremendous waste.  You would basically be duplicating the list data for n number of users.  Also removing/adding new items to the system would be a nightmare since it would have to iterate through all users.  #2 seems preferable, but it too has issues.  You could end up making a lot of extra and unnecessary calls to the DB in order to guarantee 10 new products.  As a user goes through more and more products, there are less new ones to choose from, so the chances of having to throw one away and get new one from the DB greatly increases.

Is there an alternative solution?  My first and primary concern is performance.  I will give up disk space in order to optimize performance.

Comment: Option 1 looks bad (specially if you're going to be regularly adding and removing products from the general list), I would go for Option 2. For option 2, you could simply ask for products that are *not* in the user's list and pick random ones from that set.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree Null.  I was just listing out the only options I could think of.  I don't really like either solution...

Comment: The only qualm I have with option 2 is, over time you'll have users who will have an enormous list of previously seen products, which could be a problem.

Comment: Option 2 seem to be the right way to go about it. If you need to keep track of what the user has seen, you have to save the list somewhere. To use a cliche, you have to break an egg to make an omelette.

Answer (score 0):

Those 2 ways are a complete waste of both primary and secondary memory.
You want to show 2 never before seen products, but is this a real must?
If you have a lot of products 10 random ones have a high chance of being unique.

3 . You could list 10 random products, even though not as easy as in MySQL, still less complicated than 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care how random the sequence of id's is you could do this:

Create a single randomized table of just product id's and a sequential integer surrogate key column.  Start each customer at a random point in the list on first login and cycle through the list ordered by that key.  If you reach the end, start again from the top.

The customer record would contain a single value for the last product they saw (the surrogate from the randomized list, not the actual id).  You'd then pull the next ten on login and do a single update to the customer.  It wouldn't really be random, of course.  But this kind of table-seed strategy is how a lot of simpler pseudo-random number generators work.

The only problem I see is if your product list grows more quickly than your users log in.  Then they'd never see the portions of the list which appear before wherever they started.  Even so, with a large list of products and very active users this should scale much better than storing everything they've seen.  So if it doesn't matter that products appear in a set psuedo-random sequence, this might be a good fit for you.

Edit:

If you stored the first record they started with as well, you could still generate the list of all things seen.  It would be everything between that value and last viewed.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this: crate a collection `prodUser` where you will have just the id of the product and the list of customersID, (who have seen these products) .

```
{
  prodID : 1,
  userID : []
}
```

when a customer logs in you find the 10 prodID which has not been assigned to that user

```
db.prodUser.find({
  userID : {
    $nin : [yourUser]
  }
})
```

(For some reason $not is not working :-(. I do not have time to figure out why. If you will - plz let me know.). After showing the person his products - you can update his prodUser collection. To mitigate mongos inability to find random  elements - you can insert elements randomly and just find first 10.

Everything should work really fast.